# Changing fontsize of colorbar labels in healpy.mollview()

Tags: python, matplotlib, healpy

I'm using healpy's `mollview()` function (http://healpy.github.com/healpy/generated/healpy.visufunc.mollview.html) to plot a map. I can specify a title and label for the colorbar, but I don't see how I can change the font size. Sorry if this isn't the right place to post this question... I couldn't find anywhere to ask it on healpy's project page. I also can't tag the question as "healpy" because I don't have enough reputation and no one has ever asked a question about healpy before.

Answer (score 4):

Another late response:

Unfortunately, the `rcParams` doesn't work for the `units` problem, since that's a `text` object in the `hp.visufunc.mollview` function.

```
import healpy as hp
import numpy as np
import matplotlib

fontsize = 20

d = np.arange(12*16**2)
hp.mollview(d, title='Hello', unit=r'T', notext=False, coord=['G','C'])

matplotlib.rcParams.update({'font.size':fontsize})
matplotlib.pyplot.show()
```

[image: incomplete]

As you can see, the text objects corresponding to the unit and the coordinate system aren't affected because they just have a separate text handling system. It's possible to change the objects by using the `gcf()` function, i.e.

```
import healpy as hp
import numpy as np
import matplotlib

fontsize = 20

d = np.arange(12*16**2)
hp.mollview(d, title='Hello', unit=r'T', notext=False, coord=['G','C'])

matplotlib.rcParams.update({'font.size':fontsize})
matplotlib.pyplot.show()

f = matplotlib.pyplot.gcf().get_children()
HpxAx = f[1]
CbAx = f[2]

coord_text_obj = HpxAx.get_children()[0]
coord_text_obj.set_fontsize(fontsize)

unit_text_obj = CbAx.get_children()[1]
unit_text_obj.set_fontsize(fontsize)

matplotlib.pyplot.show()
```

[image: complete]

Comment: fails:
`-> 1301         coord_text_obj.set_fontsize(fontsize)
   1302 
   1303         unit_text_obj = CbAx.get_children()[1]

AttributeError: 'Line2D' object has no attribute 'set_fontsize'
`

Comment: It worked fine for me using `hp.__version__ == 1.12.4`, is your `healpy` up to date?

Comment: I am getting an `IndexError: list index out of range` when calling `HpxAx = f[1]`, with `healpy` v1.14.0. Seems like `matplotlib.pyplot.gcf().get_children()` only returns a `matplotlib.patches.Rectangle` object now.

Answer (score 4):

(I cannot comment on Warpig's comment due to my low reputation)

As of July 2021, I am also getting `IndexError: list index out of range` when calling `HpxAx = f[1]`, with `healphy=1.11.0` and `matplotlib==3.0.0`. My workaround was to create the figure first, and then update it:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib import cm
import healpy as hp

matplotlib.rcParams.update({'font.size': 18}) # fontsize for colorbar's values
fontsize = 22
cm.magma.set_under("w") # set background to white

# create figure
d = np.arange(12*16**2)
hp.mollview(d, title='Hello', unit=r'T', notext=False, coord=['G','C'], cmap=cm.magma)

f = plt.gcf() # accessing the current figure...
CbAx = f.get_children()[2] # ... then the colorbar's elements
coord_text_obj = CbAx.get_children()[1] # [1] corresponds to the particular label of the
                                        # colorbar, i.e. "Field value" in this case
coord_text_obj.set_fontsize(fontsize)
plt.show()
```

Note that in this case I'm only interested in increasing the colorbar's label fontsize to 22, and the extremes of the colorbar to 18; the "Equatorial" label is not affected. If you want to save the figure, remember to do it before the `plt.show()`.

[Image link due to low reputation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XnvK3.jpg)

Answer (score 2):

sorry, late answer, but useful if somebody finds this from google:

You can change the font size for all the text in the plot updating `rcParams`:

```
import matplotlib
matplotlib.rcParams.update({'font.size': 22})
```

Answer (score 0):

This has gotten easier (yet, not optimal) by using `healpy.projview`.

I also make use of `rcParams['font.size']` to globally set the font size; however, for me this does not work out of the box for healpy plots. Changing the font size of colorbar label and tick labels only works when also passing the keyword `fontsize=dict(cbar_label='medium', cbar_tick_label='medium')`. Note also the keyword `override_plot_properties` for changing figure width as well as colorbar size and padding.

```py
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import healpy as hp

plt.rcParams['font.size'] = 8
plt.rcParams['figure.figsize'] = 3.2, 2.0
fw, fh = plt.rcParams['figure.figsize']

d = np.arange(12*16**2) - 1535.5

hp.projview(
    d, coord=['G', 'C'], cmap='planck', min=-1500, max=+1500,
    override_plot_properties=dict(figure_width=fw, cbar_shrink=0.8, cbar_label_pad=7),
    cbar_ticks=np.linspace(-1500, 1500, 7), unit='cbar label',
    fontsize=dict(title='large', 
                  xlabel='medium', ylabel='medium', 
                  xtick_label='medium', ytick_label='medium', 
                  cbar_label='medium', cbar_tick_label='medium'),
)
```

This produces the following plot:

[image: setting healpy mollview colorbar font size]

Note, I was using matplotlib version 3.8.2 and healpy version 1.16.6 for this.